# Azure App(native) Silent Authentication without user interaction

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory

I wanted to take a backup of dynamics crm instance using Online Management [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/admin.services.crm.dynamics.com) . Basically i wanted to take a back up of Full CRM instance everyday without user interaction . Sample Code given by MS requires a login windows which we don't need and I didn't find a way to exclude login window.

[Sample Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/online-management-api/sample-quick-start)

Comment: Do you want to run your application as a desktop application? or a daemon? or a Web application? do you want to use the Windows integrated security?

Comment: I want to run application as windows service or console application (background)

Answer (score 0):

Running it as a Daemon, Windows Service, you could use the App Permissions and just get an App only token via the Authentication Flow documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) with a link to some code samples on that.  Now, if you run it as a user account with delegated permissions, you could try the "client_secret_post" authentication method for the token acquisition mentioned here and in more detail with the [OpenID Connect Spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClientAuthentication) and the [OAuth 2.0 Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1). There is a Wiki on that in the Azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token).

Comment: we have tried using daemon App as well as silent authentication using certificate but when i tried to use access token to call Online Management API - it always say you are not authorized. Yet i am trying one more time

Comment: I am able to get access token using Daemon-Certificate credentials but when i use same token to get instances it says "Authorization has been denied for the request" Although i am passing correct resource URL when accessing token

Comment: Have you checked the Token claims using https://jwt.ms? If the claims are correct, but you still have access denied, has an Admin "granted" those permissions in the AAD registration?

Comment: Do you know if the permissions have been granted to the application via Admin consent? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference

Comment: Yes, i have checked , i have given permission of Office Management API as well as given Admin consent too. I didn't check token claims with jwt.ms ?

Comment: I am able to generate token using postman with help of this article https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/193506?pi51685=1#responses but when i try to use same token for getting instance backup it says "Authorization has been denied for this request"

Comment: Are the permissions correct on the Application? The API documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/online-management-api/authentication they call out in the [Registration Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt622431.aspx). That refers to the permissions on the "Dynamics CRM Online" application API.  But I know for us at least, we have several instances of CRM registered, so a search for Dynamics in the Azure portal showed us all of them.  I wonder if this is a resource/permission issue more than a token?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the code samples you'd want to use for a daemon app [Daemon applications (accessing Web APIs with the application's identity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#daemon-applications-accessing-web-apis-with-the-applications-identity)

you have a choice of .NET or .NET Core samples, and even one Java one and an ASP.NET Web App.